# Select all but one column of HTML table

Tags: html, html-table, append, export-to-excel, getselection

I'm using the following to select a table element in my application for users to drag/drop a table into Excel:

```
$('#footer').on("click", "#exportSel", function () {
    var el = document.getElementById(curTable);
    var body = document.body, range, sel;
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
        range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection;
        if (sel) {
            if (sel.removeAllRanges) {
                sel.removeAllRanges();
            } else if (sel.empty) {
                sel.empty();
            }
        }
        try {
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        } catch (e) {
            range.selectNode(el);
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
    }
});
```

...and everything is working fine.  Except one of my tables has images in a column, and I would like remove this column (or td's in that column) from the selection.

I added the "Picture" td's to a "nosel" class, and was able to put all td's in the table not in that class into a variable:

```
cells = $("#" + curTable + " tr td:not(.nosel)");
```

I then omitted the code to remove or empty the current selection, and tried adding each cell to the selection:

```
range.selectNode(cells[i]);
sel.addRange(range);
```

... but only the first td is being selected.

So two questions:

1. Is this even possible?
2. Is there a better method to use than addRange?  I tried extend but that did not work.

As requested, here is an example of my table:

```
<table class="sortable" id="resultsTable" border="1">
    <thead id="resultsHeader">
        <th>OID</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Parcel ID</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resultsBody" data-ssimplename="results">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td align="center" class="nosel"><img style="width: 125px;" src="http://www.vanderburghassessor.org/assessor_images/12/180/34/213/020/12-180-34-213-020-S.jpg"></td>
            <td align="center">5830 N KERTH AVE</td>
            <td align="center">82-06-04-034-213.020-020</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function from jQuery.

```
$('myElements').not('myExcludedElements');
```

**UPDATE:**

JSFiddle would not load up for me for some reason so here it is in CodePen instead.

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kjery)

Comment: I would be happy to provide a fiddle with a more specific example if you can give me an example of your html to work with.

Comment: chockleyc - thank you for reply.  I have provided an example of my table above.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example.  I apologize for the delay I usually only check SO at work.

Comment: It appears I am going to have to change a few things with my selection function to implement this.  I see how I can easily get the td's that are not '.nosel', however the selection function I am using selects the table element, and not the td elements.  I'm still having trouble appending the selection from one td to another.  Thanks for the info about.not(), however!

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go about this another way.

Instead of removing the Image column from the selection, I am going to convert the images to the URL string when they make the selection:

`

```
for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var urlT = $(imgs[i]).attr('src');
    $(imgs[i]).hide();
    $(imgs[i]).parent().text(urlT);
}
```

`

This way the URL still exists to the image if in fact someone wants it.

The only issue is trying to restore the image once the selection is cleared.  I tried adding an .on() function but it doesn't want to work correctly:

`

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
    if ($("#" + curTable + " img:hidden").length > 0) {
        var imgs = $('#' + curTable + " img:hidden");
        for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            $(imgs[i]).parent().text() = '';
            imgs[i].show();
        }
    }
});
```

`

I can deal with it not restoring, but obviously I would prefer if it did.